# facebook like button

Tags: php, facebook

i am using facebook like buttton

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href={url}&amp;layout=button_count&amp;"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; width:150px; height:25px">/iframe>
```

=>{url} is dynamic value

also i am using

```
$facebook->api_client->fql_query('SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE post_id="{url}"');
```

to fetch the users who likes the product but i am not getting any output.

Plz help.

Answer (score 3):

Won't you have to use `{$url}` instead?

It is also better to encode the `$url` using `urlencode()` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,yes i am using $url eventhough it is not working. eg $url="http://qqqqq/pdtdetail/1"

Answer (score 0):

In response to the other answer by 動靜能量,

I don't think that should be encoded with urlencode since it is in a string.

Instead, check if you have magicquotes enabled (you can check the status with the command `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`)

If you have magicquotes enabled, you don't have to screen the input, it is already filtered. If it is not enabled, instead of urlencode, use addslashes. I believe the code would be:

```
$facebook->api_client->fql_query('SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE post_id="{'.addslashes(url).'}"');
```